# Print image location and put the image in image view

Tags: android, file-upload, imageview

I am writing a android code to get the image location and after getting that put the physical image into a image view. SO far I have written code to open a popup window which allows user to select a file.

```
final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
    "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);

} catch (Exception ex) {

    Log.d("File upload", "error" + ex.toString());
}

Log.d("File Location", ":" + intent.getData().getPath());
```

I Tried this to get the location but it didnt show anything.

Now how do I get the file location and put it in a image view??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this code for setting image in imageview.

```
package com.android.imagegalleray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageGalleryDemoActivity extends Activity {


private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }


   }
}
```